# Violating t-Test assumption

Tags: t-test

Given the following setup:

1. I measure the count of an event in 30 datasets (stock prices). Hence, I get 30 observations with a count $N^{o}_i$ (with $i = 1,...,30$).
2. I bootstrap/sample the stock prices 100 times for each dateset.
3. In each of the artificial datasets, I do the same and count how often the event happens and get $N^{a}_{i,j}$ with $j = 1,...,100$ observations.
4. I now want to know if the number of events in the original and artificial datasets is significantly different. Hence, I calculate $\Delta N_{i,j} = N^{0}_i - N^{a}_{i,j}$ for each dateset. This is the difference between original count and corresponding 100 counts from the artificial datasets. If there is no difference the mean $\Delta \bar{N_{i,j}}$ should be 0.
5. I use a t-Test to check if the true mean of the differences is 0 ($H_0: \Delta \bar{N_{i,j}} = 0$ vs $H_A: \Delta \bar{N_{i,j}} != 0$).

**Question 1:**
Is the setup ok because I test simulated data vs original data (but not directly as the count of events should be independent). Hence, I have only one observation per dataset from which I subtract $100$ observations from the simulated datasets.

**Question 2:**
How can I estimate the bias when violating the normality assumptions for the t-test.  I found conflicting information so far. It would be great to get a reliable source in a reply.

Here is an example visual example of the data

[image]

Comment: Would we expect the number of counts in the bootstrapped samples center around the number of counts in the original data as the number of bootstrapped sets approach infinity?

Comment: Good question. Yes, under $H_0$ they should be the same. This would mean that both price series have the same systematic to produce events. If the original series has some internal systematic that produces more or less events, it would mean that the artificial prices lose this systematic. Does this help? If not I can elaborate on the background.